# PHP: shell_exec git pull pass passphrase

Tags: php, git, gitlab, shell-exec

I have the script PHP follow:

```
shell_exec('D: && cd D:\Xampp\htdocs\demo_gitlab && git pull');
```

(Update gitlab with PHP)
When i test with the command window, then result:

```
C:\Users\nknha>D: && cd D:\Xampp\htdocs\demo_gitlab && git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/nknha/.ssh/hsdichvu': 
remote: Counting objects: 3, done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done. 
remote: Total 3 (delta 2), reused 1 (delta 0) 
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done. 
From gitlab.com:huesoft/diet-tru-sau
    7e940be..22886d0  master     -> origin/master Updating 7e940be..22886d0 
Fast-forward
  README.md | 4 +++-
  1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

So how can enter the passphrase when running command **shell_exec**

Answer (score 0):

You can not as it is a part of the external program.
 You can only pass it as an argument. I would suggest to create a separate shell script and run it with `shell_exec()`.